# Slow upload on HTTP not on Websocket

Tags: performance

My fibre network 100 Down /100 Up is usually measured at around 115/115 Mbps. But now it is reading 115/8 when measuring the most common reference site in Sweden, Bredbandskollen.se.

Now, when I choose Advanced and measure HTTP only, I can get as low as 100/0,2 Mbps. Measuring over Websockets only, I get full speed again. I measure direct in from the ISP, no router involved, and I get the same readings with different computers, different browsers and different cables.

My ISP support is very reluctant to discuss this problem - and I will soon try to convince them again that this does not look normal, because I have network problems that might be related to this.

Does anyone have an explanation to this behaviour? Speednet shows good numbers, but I have learned that it is measured with/over (I dont know what to say there) WebSocket.

Comment: Take a capture of the HTTP flow, and have a look at it. Since both HTTP and WS traffic is over TCP, slow HTTP suggests that something on the application layer is causing it...

Comment: Thank you - how can I do that capure? I do not know much about these things. And what do you mean wiht "Application layer"?

Comment: I read about application layer, so you do not have to explain. But I am interested in how to capture the HTTP traffic

Comment: Use a tool for that purpose such as Wireshark.

Comment: Well that was way too complex to me.